# Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension : Cannot bind parameter 'StorageContext'

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-worker-roles, diagnostics

I got the below error while running this script

```
$storage_name = "<storage name>"
$key = "<key>"
$config_path="C:\diagnostics.wadcfgx"
$service_name="<service name>"
$storageContext = (New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storage_name -StorageAccountKey $key)
Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension -StorageContext $storageContext -DiagnosticsConfigurationPath $config_path -ServiceName $service_name -Slot Staging -Role WorkerRole1
```

Followed by error :

```
Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension : Cannot bind parameter 'StorageContext'. Cannot convert the "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.AzureStorageContext" value of type
"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.AzureStorageContext" to type "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.AzureStorageContext".
```

Comment: I'm getting the same when running my script under Azure Automation runbook but runs fine locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the variable $storageContext and passed the storage account name and key value directly into the command like below.

```
Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension -ServiceName $cloudService_name -Role $cloudWorkerRole_Name -StorageAccountName $wr_storageaccount_name -StorageAccountKey $wr_storageaccount_key -DiagnosticsConfigurationPath $local_configuration_path  -Slot Production
```

It worked.Thanks